# Threading timer function not working within multiprocessing recursive script

Tags: python, recursion, timer, multiprocessing

I am a biologist and I am new to parallel processing. Some important background is that some of my scripts can take up to 15hrs to execute. While the main function (in_command) is running I am trying to run in parallel a function that will take snapshots of the hardware usage (CPU, RAM, etc.). The problem I am having is that my recursive script that is on a timer (get_stats) is executing correctly when it ran separately, but as soon as I run it in parallel using multiprocessing the timer doesn't seem to work. The function runs about every second even though I have it on a 300second timer. It does stop after the other script has finished, but I get way more snapshots than needed. I am also not in love with my current approach so if there is a better way to do it I am willing to learn. I just can't have it impact the other script too much hence the snapshot approach, I only need to know generally what is happening. Thanks!

```
import psutil
import platform
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing
import time
import os
from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing as mp



def get_size(bytes, suffix="B"):
    """
    Scale bytes to its proper format
    e.g:
        1253656 => '1.20MB'
        1253656678 => '1.17GB'
    """
    factor = 1024
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P"]:
        if bytes < factor:
            return f"{bytes:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        bytes /= factor


def get_stats(switch, snapshot_dict, beg_time):
    df =snapshot_dict
    start_time = beg_time
    df['time'].append(time.time() - start_time)
   
    # Get core information
    df['total_cores'].append(psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))
    df['physical_cores'].append(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
    cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
    
    # cpu frequency in Mhz
    df['max_frequency'].append(cpufreq.max)
    df['min_frequency'].append(cpufreq.min)
    df['current_frequency'].append(cpufreq.current)
    cpu_core = {}
    for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
        cpu_core[str(i)] = percentage
    df['cpu_core'].append(cpu_core)
    
    # get ram information
    svmem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    df['total_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.total))
    df['available_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.available))
    df['used_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.used))
    df['percent_memory'].append(svmem.percent)
    
    # swap memory if it exists
    swap = psutil.swap_memory()
    df['swap_total'].append(get_size(swap.total))
    df['swap_free'].append(get_size(swap.free))
    df['swap_used'].append(get_size(swap.used))
    df['swap_percentage'].append(swap.percent)
    print(df)

    #Call the code on a recursive function
    t = Timer(300, get_stats(switch,df,beg_time))
    t.start()

    print('Switch: ', switch.value)
    if switch.value == 1:
        t.cancel()


def in_command(file,switch):
    f = open(file,'r')
    f_lines = f.readlines()
    for line in f_lines:
        print(line)
        os.system(line)
    f.close()
    switch.value += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

    manager= mp.Manager()

    df = {'time': [], 'total_cores': [], 'physical_cores': [], 'max_frequency': [],
          'min_frequency': [], 'current_frequency': [], 'cpu_core': [], 'total_memory': [],
          'available_memory': [], 'used_memory': [], 'percent_memory': [], 'swap_total': [],
          'swap_free': [], 'swap_used': [], 'swap_percentage': []}


    process_switch = manager.Value('i',0)

    start_time = time.time()


    p1 = mp.Process(target=get_stats, args = (process_switch, df, start_time))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=in_command, args=('text_command.txt', process_switch))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('finished')
```

Comment: In `t = Timer(300, get_stats(switch,df,beg_time))` you are calling `get_stats` directly instead of handing out the function object to the timer like you did when creating the `Process`es.

Comment: `Timer(300, get_stats, args=(switch,df,beg_time))`

Comment: if you already run `get_stats` in separated process then you could run it without `Timer`  but `while True: ...your code ... time.sleep(300)`. You could also use variable ot stop it `running = True` and `while running: ...your code ... time.sleep(300)` and later set `running = False` to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael. So to everyone who might be reading this, I don't include the arguments in the call function but I put them in separately.

Incorrect:
`t = Timer(300, get_stats(switch,df,beg_time))`

Correct:
`t = Timer(5, function=get_stats,args=[switch,snapshot_dict,beg_time])`